# Would it be possible to use a 64 GB microsd card in a phone that only support 32 GB microsd cards by reformatting the card?

Tags: android, storage, compatibility, fat32, exfat

I know that a lot of lower-end android smartphones do not support microsd cards larger than 32 GB. However, my question is, if I format a 64 GB card with FAT32 (rather than exFAT), using this program: http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?guiformat.htm , would it be possible to use it in such a smartphone?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (Smartphones). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not - the cards themselves have different formats (SDHC for cards up to 32 bit, and SDXC for bigger cards). While the SDXC format has exfat as the default file system, chances are the cards themselves would be incompatible with a SDHC only reader. Reformatting the drives with fat32 would not magically allow the cards to be used, even with a 32 gb partition